# Template Error asp

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, mono, monodevelop

I finally made my monodevelop to create an mvc3 razor project, but not everything works. When I try to create a view, it says it can not find a template. Also, when I try to create the project, it says this:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file "/usr/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/MonoDevelop.AspNet.Mvc/Templates/Common/Index.cshtml".
File name: '/usr/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/MonoDevelop.AspNet.Mvc/Templates/Common/Index.cshtml'
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean anonymous, FileOptions options) [0x0032f] in /build/mono/src/mono-3.2.3/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/FileStream.cs:320 
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share) [0x00000] in /build/mono/src/mono-3.2.3/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/FileStream.cs:132 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileStream:.ctor (string,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess,System.IO.FileShare)
  at System.IO.File.OpenRead (System.String path) [0x00000] in /build/mono/src/mono-3.2.3/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/File.cs:341 
  at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor (System.String path, System.Text.Encoding encoding, Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, Int32 bufferSize) [0x00077] in /build/mono/src/mono-3.2.3/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/StreamReader.cs:189 
  at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor (System.String path) [0x00000] in /build/mono/src/mono-3.2.3/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/StreamReader.cs:165 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.StreamReader:.ctor (string)
  at System.IO.File.ReadAllText (System.String path) [0x00000] in /build/mono/src/mono-3.2.3/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/File.cs:537 
  at MonoDevelop.Ide.Templates.TextFileDescriptionTemplate.CreateContent (System.String language) [0x00027] in /build/monodevelop/src/monodevelop-4.0.13/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Ide.Templates/TextFileDescriptionTemplate.cs:77 
  at MonoDevelop.Ide.Templates.SingleFileDescriptionTemplate.CreateContent (MonoDevelop.Projects.Project project, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2 tags, System.String language) [0x00003] in /build/monodevelop/src/monodevelop-4.0.13/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Ide.Templates/SingleFileDescriptionTemplate.cs:311 
  at MonoDevelop.Ide.Templates.SingleFileDescriptionTemplate.CreateFileContent (MonoDevelop.Projects.SolutionItem policyParent, MonoDevelop.Projects.Project project, System.String language, System.String fileName, System.String identifier) [0x0001a] in /build/monodevelop/src/monodevelop-4.0.13/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Ide.Templates/SingleFileDescriptionTemplate.cs:264 
  at MonoDevelop.Ide.Templates.SingleFileDescriptionTemplate.SaveFile (MonoDevelop.Projects.SolutionItem policyParent, MonoDevelop.Projects.Project project, System.String language, System.String baseDirectory, System.String entryName) [0x0006b] in /build/monodevelop/src/monodevelop-4.0.13/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Ide.Templates/SingleFileDescriptionTemplate.cs:204 
  at MonoDevelop.Ide.Templates.SingleFileDescriptionTemplate.AddFileToProject (MonoDevelop.Projects.SolutionItem policyParent, MonoDevelop.Projects.Project project, System.String language, System.String directory, System.String name) [0x0000a] in /build/monodevelop/src/monodevelop-4.0.13/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Ide.Templates/SingleFileDescriptionTemplate.cs:113 
  at MonoDevelop.Ide.Templates.SingleFileDescriptionTemplate.AddToProject (MonoDevelop.Projects.SolutionItem policyParent, MonoDevelop.Projects.Project project, System.String language, System.String directory, System.String name) [0x00009] in /build/monodevelop/src/monodevelop-4.0.13/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Ide.Templates/SingleFileDescriptionTemplate.cs:108 
  at MonoDevelop.Ide.Templates.DirectoryTemplate.AddToProject (MonoDevelop.Projects.SolutionItem policyParent, MonoDevelop.Projects.Project project, System.String language, System.String directory, System.String name) [0x00068] in /build/monodevelop/src/monodevelop-4.0.13/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Ide.Templates/DirectoryTemplate.cs:102 
  at MonoDevelop.Ide.Templates.DirectoryTemplate.AddToProject (MonoDevelop.Projects.SolutionItem policyParent, MonoDevelop.Projects.Project project, System.String language, System.String directory, System.String name) [0x00068] in /build/monodevelop/src/monodevelop-4.0.13/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Ide.Templates/DirectoryTemplate.cs:102 
  at MonoDevelop.Ide.Templates.ProjectDescriptor.InitializeItem (MonoDevelop.Projects.SolutionItem policyParent, MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectCreateInformation projectCreateInformation, System.String defaultLanguage, MonoDevelop.Projects.SolutionEntityItem item) [0x00224] in /build/monodevelop/src/monodevelop-4.0.13/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Ide.Templates/ProjectDescriptor.cs:162
```

I have to create the view because it doesnt make one at the start.

I tried to find a template for the razorview engine, but I can't find them.

Answer (score 4):

I just had this problem myself. I'm using arch linux.

After I got the error I uninstalled monodevelop, but not the dependencies. I then went to:

```
    https://github.com/mono/monodevelop
```

and followed the instructions there. I used

```
    git clone https://github.com/mono/monodevelop.git
    cd monodevelop
    git submodule update --init --recursive
    ./configure --profile=stable ; make ; sudo make install
```

I then went into monodevelop and created a MVC 3 project with razor and it snapped right open. No issues at all.